# Scanner is turning my computer off

Tags: ubuntu, scanner, poweroff

I'm running Ubuntu 64-bit and I just installed a printer, the Epson Stylus NX110.  Whenever I try to scan or print my computer powers off.  There doesn't seem to be anything left over in my logs, (but that isn't saying much, because if something is left it probably doesn't have time to disk sync before the power off.)

I also attempted to scan within a Virtual Machine running Windows XP.  Same issue.

This is probably a hardware issue from the symptoms.  But it's really strange.  What does Superuser say?  Bad Motherboard?  Bad Power Supply?  Bad USB Drivers under Linux?

Here is some information about my system:

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Memory controller: nVidia Corporation CK804 Memory Controller (rev a3)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: nVidia Corporation CK804 ISA Bridge (rev a3)
00:01.1 SMBus: nVidia Corporation CK804 SMBus (rev a2)
00:02.0 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation CK804 USB Controller (rev a2)
00:02.1 USB Controller: nVidia Corporation CK804 USB Controller (rev a3)
00:04.0 Multimedia audio controller: nVidia Corporation CK804 AC'97 Audio Controller (rev a2)
00:06.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation CK804 IDE (rev f2)
00:07.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation CK804 Serial ATA Controller (rev f3)
00:08.0 IDE interface: nVidia Corporation CK804 Serial ATA Controller (rev f3)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCI Bridge (rev a2)
00:0a.0 Bridge: nVidia Corporation CK804 Ethernet Controller (rev a3)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge (rev a3)
00:0c.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge (rev a3)
00:0d.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge (rev a3)
00:0e.0 PCI bridge: nVidia Corporation CK804 PCIE Bridge (rev a3)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:07.0 Network controller: RaLink RT2800 802.11n PCI
01:0a.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GT200 [GeForce GTX 260] (rev a1)
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 04b8:084d Seiko Epson Corp.
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c404 Logitech, Inc. TrackMan Wheel
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:0990 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Pro 9000
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
autofs4                28057  1 
binfmt_misc             7960  1 
vboxnetadp              5636  0 
vboxnetflt             19227  0 
vboxdrv              1817576  2 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
snd_intel8x0           31155  2 
snd_ac97_codec        125394  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus                1450  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_seq_dummy           1782  0 
snd_usb_audio          92747  1 
snd_pcm_oss            41394  0 
snd_seq_oss            31219  0 
snd_mixer_oss          16299  1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_seq_midi            5829  0 
snd_seq_midi_event      7267  2 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm                87850  4 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_pcm_oss
snd_seq                57417  7 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ppdev                   6375  0 
snd_usb_lib            18978  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_timer              23553  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_rawmidi            23388  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usb_lib
uvcvideo               62403  0 
fbcon                  39270  71 
tileblit                2487  1 fbcon
font                    8053  1 fbcon
bitblit                 5811  1 fbcon
softcursor              1565  1 bitblit
videodev               40486  1 uvcvideo
v4l1_compat            15495  2 uvcvideo,videodev
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    12020  1 videodev
snd_seq_device          6824  5 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi
snd_hwdep               6924  1 snd_usb_audio
parport_pc             29958  1 
rt2860sta             542482  1 
nvidia              10220725  40 
snd                    70978  19 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_pcm_oss,snd_seq_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep
vga16fb                12757  1 
vgastate                9857  1 vga16fb
k8temp                  3912  0 
soundcore               8052  1 snd
edac_core              45423  0 
edac_mce_amd            9214  0 
snd_page_alloc          8500  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm
i2c_nforce2             6099  0 
lp                      9336  0 
parport                37160  3 ppdev,parport_pc,lp
usbhid                 40988  0 
hid                    83376  1 usbhid
raid10                 21290  0 
raid456                54720  1 
async_raid6_recov       5945  1 raid456
async_pq                3891  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
raid6_pq               80147  2 async_raid6_recov,async_pq
async_xor               3111  3 raid456,async_raid6_recov,async_pq
xor                     4685  1 async_xor
async_memcpy            1537  2 raid456,async_raid6_recov
async_tx                2545  5 raid456,async_raid6_recov,async_pq,async_xor,async_memcpy
raid1                  22226  0 
raid0                   6778  0 
multipath               7149  0 
linear                  4158  0 
btrfs                 476631  0 
zlib_deflate           21834  1 btrfs
crc32c                  2983  1 
libcrc32c               1244  1 btrfs
floppy                 63156  0 
firewire_ohci          24735  0 
firewire_core          51537  1 firewire_ohci
crc_itu_t               1715  1 firewire_core
pata_amd               11962  3 
forcedeth              55592  0 
sata_nv                23778  3
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux oberus 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:09:38 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I know you said there was nothing in the logs, but which logs? Does dmesg show anything at that time? and where did you load the driver from - in other words, what driver is it?

Comment: The specific logs I've checked are /var/log/kern.1 /var/log/dmesg.1.gz /var/log/syslog.1 /var/log/messages.1.  The driver used is the built-in it automatically installed, cups prompted me for a file, I used the one for Stylus NX115.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the driver? Here is a link I found that might help, although I have not used it myself: http://www.openprinting.org/driver/epson-stylus-nx110-series/

Comment: Defective printer?

Comment: This is a possibility, but it works under MacOSX 10.5 on a different computer.  It's also a possibility that it's an issue with my motherboard's USB controller or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd try (if you're not already) is using a **mains powered** USB hub.  Maybe the printer is pulling just enough power to knock your Motherboard or PSU over the edge.

Answer (score 1):

I found that not all my USB ports on all my computers are the same.  It matters very much WHICH USB socket (& port) is being used.  If you have a modern USB connection, it gets worse, with USB3, etc.

I assume you've checked that it is not a cable, nor the scanner's problem?

AFAIK most printers have a self-test mode,independent of any connections anywhere else.  We assume you've check that the scanner-printer is ok.

Generally I have two Linux systems on my computers.  Usually only Win7 or Linux crashes.  I've yet to discover how I can have two Win7 op systems on the one hard disk.